# Loop for the Set

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> h;
Set set = h.entrySet();     
Iterator i = set.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i.next());
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
            String currentSegString = (String) me.getKey();

            System.out.println(currentKey+"**************");
        }
```

Prints out this:

```
1=[]
2**************
3=[A, B, C]
4**************
5=[]
```

But then I remove one line `System.out.println(i.next());`:

```
LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> h;
Set set = h.entrySet();     
Iterator i = set.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
            String currentSegString = (String) me.getKey();

            System.out.println(currentKey+"**************");
        }
```

And it prints out this:

```
1**************
2**************
3**************
4**************
5**************
```

Why doesn't it print `**************` in the first case for each key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because when you do :

```
System.out.println(i.next());
```

You are skipping to the next line, and then the `Map` also does `.next()`

Therefor you are only seeing 2 out of the possible 5 lines.

Explanation:

```
     while(i.hasNext()) { 
        System.out.println(i.next()); //skip one  #1, #3, #5
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); //goto next one #2, #4
        String currentSegString = (String) me.getKey();

        System.out.println(currentKey+"**************"); //output #2,4
    }
```

Second code:

```
    while(i.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next(); //goto next one #1, #2, #3, #4, #5
        String currentSegString = (String) me.getKey();

        System.out.println(currentKey+"**************"); //output #1,2,3,4,5
    }
```

A way to fix this would be:

```
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Object temp = i.next(); //goto next one #1, #2, #3, #4, #5
        System.out.println(temp);
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)temp; 
        String currentSegString = (String) me.getKey();

        System.out.println(currentKey+"**************"); //output #1,2,3,4,5
    }
```

Comment: @Neal: How do I print out the content of the i without skipping the line? So I would like to actually see '1=[]'?

Comment: @Neal: What would it be in my case "Where someType would be the type that i.next() is"?

Comment: @Prostak i have no idea what type your `i.next()` is. Try `Object` but I could be wrong

Comment: @Prostak, no problem, anytime, ill update my answer with `Object`

Answer (score 2):

In the first piece of code, you have two calls to i.next(), which means that your loop will only execute fewer times than in the second piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code should look like to get your desired output:

```
Map.Entry me;
LinkedHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> h;
Set set = h.entrySet();     
Iterator<Map.Entry> i = set.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) 
{
    me = i.next();
    System.out.println(me);
    String currentSegString = (String) me.getKey();
    System.out.println(currentKey+"**************");
}
```

This way you only call `i.next();` once.